# Can you filter and watch for a contracts state changing method in web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, nodejs

Let's say I have a very simple contract:

```
 contract basicStorage {
     uint storedData;

     function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
     }

     function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
     }
 }
```

I would like to watch for changes on set() which I believe changes the contracts state, is it possible using filter/watch in web3.js?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to use events.

**Smart-Contract - Log events**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract basicStorage {
    uint storedData;

    event SetEvent(
        address indexed _from,
        uint _x
    );

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;

        // Log event
        SetEvent(msg.sender, x);
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

The code above logs an event each time the function `set(x)` is executed. The log contains the sender address and the argument *x*.

**Web3 - Watch events**

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var abi = [...];
var address = '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var basicStorageContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var basicStorageContractInstance = basicStorageContract.at(address);

// watch for changes
var myEvent = basicStorageContractInstance.SetEvent({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});

console.log("Start watching events"); 
myEvent.watch(function(error, result){
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(error);  
    }
});



// Send a transaction to call Set
console.log("set(10)"); 
basicStorageContractInstance.set(10, {from: '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});

console.log("set(20)"); 
basicStorageContractInstance.set(20, {from: '0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
```

This code compiles the contract and retrieves an `myEvent` object which can be used to watch for an event (in our case that represents a state change).

Then sends two transactions and check if some logs are printed.

**Result**

```
{ logIndex: 0,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  transactionHash: '0x0dc9c421f4d15baa00249f8d1d55d75ea267bc4c82b9654e3c24daf69f9c529d',
  blockHash: '0x2814a29a8c3e32d66063472c6e1d9e5c8eee159f7d19d5da6ecc4bdeeeb9449c',
  blockNumber: 22,
  address: '0xa07ddaff6d8b7aabf91ac6f82bf89455eb9784f4',
  type: 'mined',
  event: 'SetEvent',
  args:
   { _from: '0x13a0674c16f6a5789bff26188c63422a764d9a39',
     _x: { [String: '20'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Array] } } }

{ logIndex: 0,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  transactionHash: '0x62d888d67e4392b7d218cc7a678b7f3168bcdd2fd77b5a51507e2bf62948273d',
  blockHash: '0x737fce60e8a2012f25eca24d8e56a13eeb127641cc89938f5ec3d8764131f7c7',
  blockNumber: 23,
  address: '0xa07ddaff6d8b7aabf91ac6f82bf89455eb9784f4',
  type: 'mined',
  event: 'SetEvent',
  args:
   { _from: '0x13a0674c16f6a5789bff26188c63422a764d9a39',
     _x: { [String: '30'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Array] } } }
```

You can find more info

- [Solidity doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events)
- [Web3 doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract)

Comment: This is pretty much the only answer. I suppose its possible to poll the contract for state change, but why bother?

Comment: I should have specified that although I am aware of events, the documentation and other online  examples somehow hint to what @OneChillDude is saying, polling for txHash and then calling a getter upon setting.Hope this answer if definitive helps others.

Comment: @Keno it does not make any sense to me to use polling over events. Events get emitted, can be search/are indexable, while polling is just more overhead you have to manage on your own

Comment: Yeah sorry for the duplicate section. I edited the answer. I agree with @OneChillDude when he says that an overhead to poll the contract. Event are here specifically for this purpose.